# Уменьшает ли функция WaitForSingleObject счетчик семафора, если она возвращает значение, отличное от WAIT_OBJECT_0?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, семафоры

Нужно ли вызвать `ReleaseSemaphore` в следующей ситуации?

```
HANDLE hSemaphore = OpenSemaphore(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, TEXT("Global\\Semaphore"));
DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, 0);
if (dwWaitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, NULL);  // ???
}
```

Comment: Нет, не уменьшает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии к вопросу есть ответ: ***нет, не уменьшает***.